# How to delete a file in a google drive shared drive folder using php?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

All I need is to delete a file which is inside my shared drive folder using google/apiclient using php , this is my code below .

```
session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // ready the API to upload to drive

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $file = $_POST['file'];

        $client = new Client();
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./credentials.json');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);

        $delete = $driveService->files->delete($file);

        if ($delete) {
            $_SESSION['success'] = "Video deleted successfully";
            header("Location: upload");
        }

}
```

Comment: Ok... so... what's not working? What error message are you getting? Note that nothing ever sets a value for `$delete` so it's never going to evaluate to true.

Comment: @Alex Howansky Sir thank you for replying, actually what I need is to delete a file from my shared drive folder and this says (  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "File not found: )

Comment: is this code even requesting authorization?

Comment: @DalmTo no i am using my service account sir

Comment: @DalmTo yes i checked it sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client has permission for deleting the file from the shared Drive, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$delete = $driveService->files->delete($file);
```

#### To:

```
$fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the file you want to delete.
try {
    $driveService->files->delete($fileId, array('supportsAllDrives' => true));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

- In this case, when the file is deleted, no value is returned. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- When I tested this script, I confirmed that a file in a shared Drive could be deleted. But, if an error occurs, please confirm the permission of your client, again.

#### Reference:

- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

Comment: Ok Sir I will check now

Comment: Sir your code worked thanks alot.

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.